# Appallingly dim UITableView question

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm sure this is a very dumb question (or one that reveals terrifying levels of ignorance), but as an iOS newbie I'm trying to lash an app together as a favour to a friend - and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a multi-tab app, which is running fine. On the last tab, I'd like have a table view giving access to a variety of pdf or html files, to be stored in the bundle (and added to in future updates). Basically I want it so that if the user selects "Story pdf" in the table view, it loads up NextView with a UIWebView showing said pdf. If they select "Info table" then that UIWebView loads up info.html instead. It'll only ever be those two file types.

I've got the table view running and a new view ready and waiting, I just can't work out the next bit. Should I store names/file types in a plist? Is NSFileManager my friend here? If anyone has any pointers or knows of a sample project or chunk of code that does something similar, it would be fantastic.

Thanks for listening :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableView will have a delegate (possibly your view controller) and you need to implement this method from the UITableViewDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you get the indexPath of the selected cell and then you work out what to do next.

Comment: Hey - many thanks for the reply. I have that bit running - my problem is working out how to translate that index into loading these specific files up into the UIWebView. I'm aware this is an ignorance problem - I'll keep banging my head against it :-) Thanks again.